# SQL Split a monthly query report to daily basis

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, split, report

i am have a query that on given dates, it founds the quantity of all materials in a store.
For example for dates 1/5/2017 and 1/6/2017 it will give me for each material in the store

```
 material   | Initial QTY | Initial Volume | Changes_QTY  | changes_volume | finalQTY | final_volume

 material1  |    10       |   100          | 2            |  20            |         8|   80
```

i want the same think (initial and final) but the period between them splitted per day and not all together.

my query is

```
SELECT mtr.code
   , mtr.DESCRIPTION
   , mtr.volume
   , Isnull((SELECT Sum(i.PRIMARYQTY * i.INPUTQUANTMODE) - Sum(i.PRIMARYQTY * i.OUTPUTQUANTMODE)
             FROM   itemtrans i
             WHERE  comid = mtr.comid
                AND i.iteid = mtr.id
                AND i.trndate < {@VFrom}
                AND i.stoid = 32
                AND i.comid = 21
             GROUP  BY i.iteid), 0) Initial_qty
   , Isnull((SELECT Sum(i.PRIMARYQTY * i.INPUTQUANTMODE) - Sum(i.PRIMARYQTY * i.OUTPUTQUANTMODE)
             FROM   itemtrans i
             WHERE  comid = mtr.comid
                AND i.iteid = mtr.id
                AND i.trndate <= {@VFrom}
                AND i.stoid = 32
                AND i.comid = 21
             GROUP  BY i.iteid), 0) * mtr.volume initial_volume
   , Isnull((SELECT Sum(i.PRIMARYQTY * i.INPUTQUANTMODE) - Sum(i.PRIMARYQTY * i.OUTPUTQUANTMODE)
             FROM   itemtrans i
             WHERE  comid = mtr.comid
                AND i.iteid = mtr.id
                AND i.TRNDATE >= {@VFrom}
                AND i.trndate <= {@VTo}
                AND i.stoid = 32
                AND i.comid = 21
             GROUP  BY i.iteid), 0) changes_qty
   , Isnull((SELECT Sum(i.PRIMARYQTY * i.INPUTQUANTMODE) - Sum(i.PRIMARYQTY * i.OUTPUTQUANTMODE)
             FROM   itemtrans i
             WHERE  comid = mtr.comid
                AND i.iteid = mtr.id
                AND i.TRNDATE >= {@VFrom}
                AND i.trndate <= {@VTo}
                AND i.stoid = 32
                AND i.comid = 21
             GROUP  BY i.iteid), 0) * mtr.volume volume_changes
   , Isnull((SELECT Sum(i.PRIMARYQTY * i.INPUTQUANTMODE) - Sum(i.PRIMARYQTY * i.OUTPUTQUANTMODE)
             FROM   itemtrans i
             WHERE  comid = mtr.comid
                AND i.iteid = mtr.id
                AND i.trndate <= {@VTo}
                AND i.stoid = 32
                AND i.comid = 21
             GROUP  BY i.iteid), 0) final_qty
   , Isnull((SELECT Sum(i.PRIMARYQTY * i.INPUTQUANTMODE) - Sum(i.PRIMARYQTY * i.OUTPUTQUANTMODE)
             FROM   itemtrans i
             WHERE  comid = mtr.comid
                AND i.iteid = mtr.id
                AND i.trndate <= {@VTo}
                AND i.stoid = 32
                AND i.comid = 21
             GROUP  BY i.iteid), 0) * mtr.volume final_volume
FROM   material mtr
       INNER JOIN STOREFINDATA STF ON STF.MASTERID = MTR.ID
WHERE  mtr.comid = 21
   AND mtr.igtid = 100
   AND stf.stoid = 32
```

i hope i made my self clear enough to help me.
Thanks

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (That query is product specific.)

Comment: i am using mssql server 2008.

Comment: Provide the table structures

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Please post original query that produces above data lines so we can see it is for 1/5 - 1/6. And how does that relate to larger query posted?